# JavaScript AJAX: Stop endless scroll when request returns empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am working on endless scroll. Every time page reaches bottom, ajax call is made for new set of data. But how to stop ajax call for new data, if there is no more data and request for data returns null or empty response?

```
var page = 1;
    var endOfDb  = false;
    var fetchUrl = "{{ path('gallery_gallery_fetch') }}";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        fetchGallery();

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (endOfDb ==false) {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $("#footer").height() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
                    fetchGallery();
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function fetchGallery() {
        endOfDb  = true;
        $.get(fetchUrl, {'page': page}).success(function (response) {
            if (response != "" || !isEmpty(response)) {
                endOfDb  = false;
            }
            $("#gallery_prints").append("<li>" + response + "</li>");
            page++;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does your success function get triggered if you receive a null or empty response? If not, you could try adding a .failure function on the .get request.

Comment: `stop` is a confusing name. You need a new variable `isFetching`, then you'll see that you need another variable, `isAtEndOfList`. Now change your check to be `if (!isFetching && !isAtEndOfList`)`

Comment: You should not plug into the scroll event like that your going to flood the client with events instead you should set a timeout and rebind to the event see this article http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var page = 1;
stop = false;
var fetchUrl = "{{ path('gallery_fetch') }}";

$(document).ready(function () {
    fetchGallery();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (stop == false) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $("#footer").height() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
                fetchGallery();
            }
        }
    });
});

function fetchGallery() {
    $.get(fetchUrl, {'page': page}).success(function (response) {
        if (response != "" || !isEmpty(response)) {
            stop = true;
        }
        $("#gallery").append("<li>" + response + "</li>");
        page++;
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
var page = 1;
stop = false;
var fetchUrl = "{{ path('gallery_fetch') }}";

$(document).ready(function () {
    fetchGallery();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $("#footer").height() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
            fetchGallery();
        }
    });
});

function fetchGallery() {
    if (stop == false) {
        stop = true;
        $.get(fetchUrl, {'page': page}).success(function (response) {
            if (response != "" || !isEmpty(response)) {
                stop = true;
            }
            $("#gallery").append("<li>" + response + "</li>");
            page++;
            stop = false;
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
var page = 1;
stop = false;
var fetchUrl = "{{ path('gallery_fetch') }}";

$(document).ready(function () {
    fetchGallery();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $("#footer").height() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
            fetchGallery();
        }
    });
});

function fetchGallery() {
    if (stop == false) {
        $.get(fetchUrl, {'page': page}).success(function (response) {
            if (response == "" || isEmpty(response)) {
                stop = true;
            }else{
                $("#gallery").append("<li>" + response + "</li>");
                page++;
                stop = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it stopped doing requests at all

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work, it still keeps making ajax requests, even though there is no more data in db

Comment: no, after first fetchGallery(); it's not doing anything

Comment: oh sry i have missed remove stop = true. retry now i have reupdated the update 2

Comment: now it's requesting page=1 multiple times in one scroll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92398/discussion-between-p-frank-and-user3793667).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var stop = 0;  
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if(stop != 0)
    {
     console.log(stop); // call your functions here
    }
   });
})
```

Replace the conditional check that you are doing before window.scroll and move it inside your window.scroll. Your function will now work depending upon the value of stop.

Answer (score 0):

there is always some response, even with no data from db. that's why i decided to check size of response like this

```
   if ( (response + '').length > 50) {
                endOfDb = false;
            }
```

No it works